# exporting output to csv file?

Tags: python, csv, twitter, export, export-to-csv

I have a code to get a tweet from its ID and I want to export the output to csv file.
Code as below:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import csv 

consumer_key = '???'
consumer_secret = '???'
access_token = '???'
access_secret = '???'


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


tweet = api.get_status(/id of tweet/)
print(tweet.text)
print(tweet.id)
print(tweet.created_at)
```

I tried this code I get it from other code and it doesn't work:

```
with open('tweet1212.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['info.']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(tweet)
```

It gets me:

```
TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable
```

please help me if you could.

Comment: Some help here please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you what was wrong - you cannot just pass in a 'Status' object into writerows.

A quick glance at the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) shows that `writerow` requires a dictionary.

So two ways:

```
with open('tweet1212.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['info.']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    row = str(tweet.text) + str(tweet.id) + str(tweet.created_at)
    writer.writerow({'info.':row})
```

Or you can change the fieldnames into `fieldnames=['text', 'id','created_at']`, and do something like`write.writerow({'text':tweet.text, 'id':tweet.id, 'created_at':tweet.created_at})`

In this way you will be writing a row only every time you open the file, so I suspect you want to do append `a` instead of write `w`:

`with open('tweet1212.csv', 'a',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`

Let me know if it works / you need any more help!

P.S. I highly recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) instead of csv to create csv files - manipulating a dataframe is much easier!

***Edit1***

Assume that you get a new tweet by running this function:

```
tweet = api.get_status(/id of tweet/)
```

then you may build a list of tweets by having something like the followings:

```
allTweets=[];
allIDs=[1234, 1235, 1236] # a lits of id of tweets that you want to get

with open('tweet1212.csv', 'a',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['info.']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for ID in allIDs:
        tweet = api.get_status(/id of tweet/)
        row = str(tweet.text) + str(tweet.id) + str(tweet.created_at)
        writer.writerow({'info.':row})
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It's good solution but does not work exactly. Because the code wrote a row only, and I did what you said I exchanged w to a and doesn't worked. Sorry if I bothered you.

Comment: My friend the code writing a row only, and I append 'a' instead 'w' and nothing change.

Comment: I am working on an update and will get back to you soon!

Comment: It appends to the csv file everytime I run the code, so it appears to be fine to me. Do you mean you want to write many rows at a time?

Comment: Not work exactly, but no problem the first solution is good. In the other subject, I want ask you is there a python code to get  a replies from a specific tweet?